# Runnig DeepPavlov Named Entity Recognition

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

How I can run NER from DeepPavlov?

I have an input file with sentences "sentences.txt" and need to put results in "result.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several choices to do named-entity recognition with DeepPavlov

The Pythonic way

```
from deeppavlov import configs, build_model

ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes, download=True)
ner_model(['Computer Sciences Corp. is close to making final an agreement to buy Cleveland Consulting Associates'])
```

and from the command line

```
python deeppavlov/deep.py interact ner_ontonotes [-d]
```